Pip install fails for pandas
I am trying to install pandas on a Windows machine but get the following output:
python -m pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-2.2.2.tar.gz (4.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [13 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\serba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6cc_jg_i\pandas_90906587555b4b9d852626b7159094db C:\Users\serba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6cc_jg_i\pandas_90906587555b4b9d852626b7159094db\.mesonpy-6bapjes7\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv --native-file=C:\Users\serba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6cc_jg_i\pandas_90906587555b4b9d852626b7159094db\.mesonpy-6bapjes7\build\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.1
      Source dir: C:\Users\serba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6cc_jg_i\pandas_90906587555b4b9d852626b7159094db
      Build dir: C:\Users\serba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6cc_jg_i\pandas_90906587555b4b9d852626b7159094db\.mesonpy-6bapjes7\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: pandas
      Project version: 2.2.2
      Activating VS 15.9.60

      ..\..\meson.build:2:0: ERROR: Value "c11" (of type "string") for combo option "C language standard to use" is not one of the choices. Possible choices are (as string): "none", "c89", "c99", "gnu89", "gnu90", "gnu9x", "gnu99".

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\serba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6cc_jg_i\pandas_90906587555b4b9d852626b7159094db\.mesonpy-6bapjes7\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I tried the following:

running the terminal as administrator
updating pip
installing older versions of pandas because I read there is some issue with the latest one
looking inside the log file from the output, but it doesn't exist anymore after the process finishes

The output is still the same.
I see it complaining about a C standard. Do I need a specific compiler to be installed or any other prerequisites?
Thanks.
Regards,
Serban

I would try to install from built file *.whl? You can download it from pypi.org

So I got past this, it was a stupid reason this was happening. I had another pip binary somewhere in a MinGW installation folder and it was always calling that one. I made sure change the environment variables to point to a proper, standalone installation of pip (also python).
